# Calculate zoom for given bounding box and map size in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, extents, zoom

Is there a way to calculate zoom for given bounding box and map size in OpenLayers?

What I can do is fitting the map and then reading the zoom from view but I need to calculate it without setting the map:

```
map.getView().fit(
    ol.proj.transformExtent(
      ol.extent.boundingExtent(boundingBox),
      ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'), ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857')
    ), {
      size: map.getSize()
    }
  );
```

then I have the zoom by:

```
map.getView().getZoom()
```

I'd like something like:

```
function calcZoom(boundingBox, map.getSize()) { ... }
```

Comment: You can fit to a different view which is not part of any map.

Comment: The zoom level is different for same bounding box on different map sizes (e.g. 300px,500px vs 500px,300px).

Comment: You can use `map.getView().getZoomForResolution(map.getView().getResolutionForExtent(extent, size))`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TomazicM I can now use:

```
let finalZoom = map.getView().getZoomForResolution(
  map.getView().getResolutionForExtent(
    ol.proj.transformExtent(
      ol.extent.boundingExtent(boundingBox),
      ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'),
      ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857')
    ),
    map.getSize()
  )
);
```